# Installing MORSE simulator on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: simulator

I've been having trouble installing MORSE.
I am trying to install it on Ubuntu 12.04 and on a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 13.04 (I don't need it on a VirtualBox, I'm just trying to make *something* work). 
On Ubuntu 12.04 I get the following errors at the cmake stage:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/oferb/opt/morse_build ..
-- will install python files in /home/oferb/opt/morse_build/lib/python3/dist-packages
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse/builder
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse/modifiers
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse/sensors
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse/multinode
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/src/morse/middleware
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/bindings
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/base
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/failures
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/robots/human
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/robots/segway
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/robots/pr2
   used as include directory in directory /home/oferb/mnt/svr_home/opt/morse/testing/robots/pionner3dx
```

On a fresh VMBox with Ubuntu 13.04, after 'morse check' succeeds, I try "morse create mysim" and get:

```
adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox:~$ morse create mysim
usage: morse [-h] [-b BASE] [--name NAME] [-c] [--reverse-color] [-g GEOM]
         [-v]
         {check,edit,run} [scene] ...
morse: error: argument mode: invalid choice: 'create' (choose from 'check', 'edit', 'run')
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I've managed to install MORSE on Ubuntu 12.04. Make sure your Blender was compiled with the same version of python (i.e python 3.2.2) that MORSE was compiled in. I used this Blender: 
http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.62

Comment: It seems that you've successfully installed morse, but are using incorrect command line arguments.  From the [latest documentation](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/stable/user/builder.html), it looks like the command you tried should have worked.  What version of morse are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04: The problem might be related to installing python3-dev or python-dev or both, in addition to specifying python3.3 specifically (if python3 directs to python3.2 by default). The cmake I'm using is: "cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/oferb/opt/morse -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ..". Now I'm stuck on the "sudo make install" part where I'm getting "Linking C shared module zbufferto3d.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04: "sudo apt-get install morse-simulator" gives you morse 1.0, but according to morse support, "morse
create" is something new in morse-1.1

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question.  I'd either see if you can find the 1.0 documentation, or install morse-1.1 from source.

Comment: @ofer, you can write the solution as an answer, then later accept it. That way, robotics.SE and its viewers would understand that the question is solved.

Comment: And as a bonus, I believe SE gives you some points and badges for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tips for MORSE on Ubuntu 12.04**:

If you're having trouble compiling MORSE, perhaps these can help:

1. Install python3-dev or python-dev or both (not sure which was needed)
2. Check which version python3 directs to. If it's the wrong one, you can specify the python version explicitly in cmake. The cmake I used is: "cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/oferb/opt/morse -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.3 .."

If you've already managed to compile MORSE, then make sure your Blender was compiled with the same version of python (i.e python 3.2.2) that MORSE was compiled in. I used this Blender: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.62.

**Tips for MORSE on Ubuntu 13.04**:

Note that "sudo apt-get install morse-simulator" gives you morse 1.0, but according to morse support, "morse create", which shows up in the tutorials, is something new in morse-1.1. You might want to search for an older tutorial, or install a more recent version of MORSE.